# What gear is recommended to absolutely destroy a pumpkin moon?

Tags: terraria-console

My brother and I recently tried fighting the Pumpkin Moon and we were destroyed by Pumpkings.

We wish to return the favor, so which gear would let us easily defeat the Pumpkin moon?

I'm playing on the XBOX version of Terraria. I'm using melee and I have a big hole in the ground (screen big) with platforms and traps at the bottom.

Comment: It really depends on which classes you are both playing as and if you have an arena or not.

Comment: If you could include class we could give you a decent build.

Answer (score -2):

Since your using a melee layout, I recommend waiting till you get Dragon Armour.
Since the melee speed, movement speed, defense, and Damage go way up. you should use ( if you have it ) a Death Sickle it's a cool high damaging weapon. You should also use Vampire knives from a crimson world as it give you life steal and is pretty fast and powerful. Get a Celestial stone, a Paladins Shield, a pair of wings, an Avenger Emblem/Destroyer Emblem, and a Star Veil. Most with Warding and some with Menacing.